# can I combine NDB and mysqldb in one app on google cloud platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore, mysql-python, app-engine-ndb

Is it just about creating models that use the best fitting data store API?

For part of the data I need relations, joins and sum(). For other this is not necessary but nosql way is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL commands cannot be run on NoSQL. You will need to do some conversions during manipulation of the data from both DBs.